# How to get screen width without (minus) scrollbar?

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, width

I have an element and need it's width without(!) vertical scrollbar.

Firebug tells me body width is 1280px.

Either of these work fine in Firefox:

```
console.log($('.element').outerWidth() );
console.log($('.element').outerWidth(true) );

$detour = $('.child-of-element').offsetParent();
console.log( $detour.innerWidth() );
```

They all return **1263px**, which is the value I'm looking for.

However all other browser give me **1280px**.

Is there a cross browser way to get a fullscreen width without(!) vertical scrollbar?

Comment: Do you need the vertical scrollbars? Or could you use overflow: hidden and then calculate the width?

Comment: you can refer to this site for the your question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794338/how-to-get-the-height-and-width-of-the-browser-viewport-without-scrollbars-using

Comment: you could try `width: 100%;`

Comment: are you trying to make the element the entire width of the screen not including the scroll bars?

Comment: With CSS: `width: calc(100vw - (100vw - 100%));` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34884924/1066234

Answer (score 194, accepted):

#### `.prop("clientWidth")` and `.prop("scrollWidth")`

```
var actualInnerWidth = $("body").prop("clientWidth"); // El. width minus scrollbar width
var actualInnerWidth = $("body").prop("scrollWidth"); // El. width minus scrollbar width
```

in **JavaScript**:

```
var actualInnerWidth = document.body.clientWidth;     // El. width minus scrollbar width
var actualInnerWidth = document.body.scrollWidth;     // El. width minus scrollbar width
```

<sub>**P.S:** Note that to use `scrollWidth` reliably your element should not overflow horizontally</sub>

**[jsBin demo](https://jsbin.com/jomiru/4/edit?html,css,js,console,output)**

---

You could also use `.innerWidth()` but this **will work only on the `body` element**

```
var innerWidth = $('body').innerWidth(); // Width PX minus scrollbar
```

Comment: This won't work if for some reason you changed the width of body element.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I changed it in CSS as a part of the design, so I don't think that would be easy. Just letting everyone else, who may get the wrong results because of it know.

Comment: It seems this doesn't truly work on Chrome any more, the reported width is actually 20px bigger than the window itself, I have tried numerous width measurements so far nothing.

Comment: @Sammaye Sorry to hear that, works in Chrome for me.

Comment: I thought it may have been version of chrome but I just updated and it still happens. The way I am testing is I have a media query at 768 and a innerWidth measurement at 768, the JS breaks at about 786 according to Chromes little size hover over on its pages. It might be implementation differences between JS width and media query width

Comment: @Sammaye ... It's hard to visualize without a demo... Can you setup a simple test case on jsBin?

Comment: Had it wrong way round, JS is smaller than media query when reporting but here is an example: http://jsbin.com/homixuqi/1/ , if you resize it to 780 it will show 764 in JS

Comment: @Sammaye that's cause you forgot (why?) to set margin:0; to BODY or use a common CSS reset code. http://jsbin.com/homixuqi/2/edit . **So again, the code works perfectly fine**.

Comment: Ok fair enough, I thought bootstrap 3.1 had reset code but it appears not

Comment: note that this method includes the **vertical scrollbar width** in the calculated width, if there is one (tested in Chrome).

Comment: This kind of works, but not for height if you needed that. Also, this is not super reliable as the size of the body can be messed with using CSS.

Comment: @NamanGoel it's your job as web designer to prevent messarounds with the body width. It's not a difficult task. Also, regarding the height it kind of depends if your `body` overflows or not. if it overflows than constrain it.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm not disagreeing with you here. Of course no good web designer/developer to should mess with the body width and stuff. My point was about using the most reliable API available. Some javascript developers may be building plug-ins etc and may not have control of the entire page.

Comment: @Fabián the jsBin demo works pretty good (Windows Ch. 66.0.3359)

Answer (score 43):

You can use vanilla javascript by simply writing:

```
var width = el.clientWidth;
```

You could also use this to get the width of the document as follows:

```
var docWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
```

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.clientWidth)

You can also get the width of the full window, including the scrollbar, as follows:

```
var fullWidth = window.innerWidth;
```

However this is not supported by all browsers, so as a fallback, you may want to use `docWidth` as above, and add on the [scrollbar width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986937/how-can-i-get-the-browsers-scrollbar-sizes/).

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.innerWidth)

Comment: This does not take into account if there is a scrollbar

Comment: `document.documentElement.clientWidth` helped me the most, because it works for height as well (`innerHeight` can be smaller if the body doesn’t fill the page, etc.) and gets the value without the scrollbar.

Comment: document.documentElement.clientWidth is the real winner.  document.body.clientWidth is ok unless you have a min-width set on your body element and the browser is currently smaller than that minimum width.

Answer (score 15):

The safest place to get the correct width and height without the scrollbars is from the HTML element. Try this:

```
var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth
var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight
```

Browser support is pretty decent, with IE 9 and up supporting this. For OLD IE, use one of the many fallbacks mentioned here.

Answer (score 12):

Here are some examples which assume `$element` is a `jQuery` element:

```
// Element width including overflow (scrollbar)
$element[0].offsetWidth; // 1280 in your case

// Element width excluding overflow (scrollbar)
$element[0].clientWidth; // 1280 - scrollbarWidth

// Scrollbar width
$element[0].offsetWidth - $element[0].clientWidth; // 0 if no scrollbar
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this :

```
$('body, html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
var screenWidth1 = $(window).width();
$('body, html').css('overflow', 'visible');
var screenWidth2 = $(window).width();
alert(screenWidth1); // Gives the screenwith without scrollbar
alert(screenWidth2); // Gives the screenwith including scrollbar
```

You can get the screen width by with and without scroll bar by using this code.
Here, I have changed the overflow value of `body` and get the width with and without scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem and doing `width:100%;` solved it for me. I came to this solution after trying an answer in this question and realizing that the very nature of an `<iframe>` will make these javascript measurement tools inaccurate without using some complex function. Doing 100% is a simple way to take care of it in an iframe. I don't know about your issue since I'm not sure of what HTML elements you are manipulating.

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me, however I was able to fix it by taking the width and subtracting the [width of the scroll bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986937/how-can-i-get-the-browsers-scrollbar-sizes). I'm not sure how cross-browser compatible this is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use

```
function windowSizes(){
    var e = window,
        a = 'inner';
    if (!('innerWidth' in window)) {
        a = 'client';
        e = document.documentElement || document.body;
    }
    return {
        width: e[a + 'Width'],
        height: e[a + 'Height']
    };  
}

$(window).on('resize', function () {
    console.log( windowSizes().width,windowSizes().height );
});
```