# Window width inconsistent between jQuery and CSS media query

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I am getting a bit of an odd result here that I can't quite understand.

In jQuery I am logging the window width by:

```
console.log( $(window).width() );
```

In my CSS I am changing the background color to red with:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

    body { background: red!important; }

}
```

Yet, in Firebug, the console says the window width is 756px wide, but the CSS makes the background red, which shouldn't happen until it reaches a minimum width of 768px.

See this screen grab for further clarification:

[image]

Can anyone explain to me why the background is red and that the CSS seems incorrect? Is it jQuery that's actually incorrect?

Also, would it have anything to do with the vertical scrollbar at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the `width` of `viewport` like,

```
function viewport() {
    var e = window, a = 'inner';
    if (!('innerWidth' in window )) {
        a = 'client';
        e = document.documentElement || document.body;
    }
    return { width : e[ a+'Width' ] , height : e[ a+'Height' ] };
}
```

[Viewport Source](http://andylangton.co.uk/blog/development/get-viewport-size-width-and-height-javascript)

Or you can use [innerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/innerwidth) like,

```
if($(window).innerWidth() <= 751) {
   $("body").css('background','red !important'); // background red
} else {
   $("body").removeAttr('style'); // remove style attribute
}
```

You can use [matchmedia](http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia) if you are not care about `IE` for egs,

```
function checkPosition() {
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
}
```

For all browsers you can try

```
if (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 767px)')) {
    //...
} else {
    //...
}
```

See [modernizr mq](http://modernizr.com/docs/#mq)

Comment: Complete post, nice one!

Comment: I went with your suggestion on using Modernizr in the end, as the others felt a bit hacky and I wanted consistent results cross-browser. Thank you. It now works as expected. It seems $(window).width() does not account for the scrollbar.

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo yes `modernizr` is the best among all.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is caused by the width of the scroll bar.

```
console.log( $(window).width() );
```

return the width of the viewport area (widthout the srcoll bar) whereas media query includes the scrollbar.

Scrollbar width varies between browsers.
In chrome for example, the background color change appears at 747px you can try in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/j8vS6/1/) with other browsers to see the diference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794338/how-to-get-the-height-and-width-of-the-browser-viewport-without-scrollbars-using

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but do you have a suggested fix?

Comment: You can force a scroll bar (this is used in normalize css) html { overflow-y: scroll;} then your widths should be more consistent.

Answer (score 0):

// Returns width of browser viewport
$( window ).width();

// Returns width of HTML document
$( document ).width();

Css will take the HTML document width. Go through this link https://api.jquery.com/width/

Answer (score 0):

You should check window width according media query for cross browser solution, something like:

```
var isWindowWidthMatchingQuery = window.matchMedia("only screen and (min-width: 768px)").matches;

alert(isWindowWidthMatchingQuery ); // returns true or false
```

See support table: http://caniuse.com/#search=matchMedia

Answer (score 0):

Don't use JavaScript to check the viewport width. It's unnecessarily complicated and prone to inconsistencies. Instead, simply check a *@media*-query dependent CSS attribute, i.e. of the class *.navbar-toggle* to check for the navbar-breakpoint (set by less variable *@screen-phone*), when using the collapsible bootstrap navbar:

```
f($(".navbar-toggle").css("display") != "none") {
    alert("Yay! I'm consistent with bootstrap!");
}
```

If you want to check the *@screen-tablet* and the *@screen-desktop* breakpoints, you can check the width of the .container class, or any other css selector in your bootstrap.css that depends on a suitable *@media*-query. Of course you can also use this technique with your own css.

Answer (score 0):

An update for this question:
Since jQuery 3.0 you can now `$(window).outerWidth()` to get the real window width including the scrollbar. It should be equal to what you can do with your CSS `@media` selectors

> Breaking change: .outerWidth() or .outerHeight() on window includes scrollbar width/height

More informations on https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-outerwidth-or-outerheight-on-window-includes-scrollbar-width-height