# Stop jquery for different screen size.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('#content-left').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=320px');
$(window).on('resize', function(){
$('#content-left').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=320px');
});
});
//]]>  
</script>
```

The above code works great but what I need is for this code to stop working or switch back to just 100% width (without subtracting the 320px) when the screen size is 768px or less.

I did some google searches and found this:

```
if ($(window).width() <= 768){  
        // do something here
    }
```

But I'm not sure how to add this to my existing code.

---

Background:

My sidebar is a fixed sidebar on the right side of the page at 300px. And I have a padding of 20px between the sidebar (#content-right) and the main section (#content-left). My main section (#content-left) is using the above script of 100% - 320px.

I am using two CSS. One is a regular CSS. The other uses:

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {}
```

Thank you. :)

Comment: Are you limited to just using JavaScript or would you be willing to entertain a CSS solution?

Comment: I tried using width: calc (100% - 320px) in CSS. But I noticed issues with browser compatibility. So I found the JavaScript mentioned in the question. But I am open to any solution.

Comment: Beware: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309859/css-media-queries-and-javascript-window-width-do-not-match  In fact you should use `window.matchMedia`   See this answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23243951/1414562

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple `if/else` statement, put your resize code in a function and call that function when the page loads and when the window is resized.

```
function resize() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
    $('#content-left').css('width', '100%');
  } else {
    $('#content-left').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=320px');

  }
}

$(window).load(function() {
  resize();
});
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  resize();
});
```

Comment: I'm very new to stackoverflow. How do I do that Mr. Taylor? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them like this.  This only runs your code when the window is NOT less than 769 pixels.  That's what the "!" symbol does, converts it to NOT.

```
$(window).load(function() {
  if (!$(window).width() <= 768) {
    $('#content-left').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=320px');
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
      $('#content-left').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=320px');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I couldn't get it to work using this code. :(