# Why does jQuery .width() does not match css media query in mobile?

Tags: jquery, mobile, width, media-queries, viewport

I would like to start of by stating I am asking *why* this is, *not* how get around it.
I am well aware of these sources here:

- [$(window).width() not the same as media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291873/window-width-not-the-same-as-media-query)
- [How to get screen width without (minus) scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339377/jquery-how-to-get-screen-width-without-scrollbar)
- [Get the height and width of the browser viewport without scrollbars using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794338/get-the-height-and-width-of-the-browser-viewport-without-scrollbars-using-jquery)
- [CSS media queries and JavaScript window width do not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309859/css-media-queries-and-javascript-window-width-do-not-match)

I have a media query implemented that is being called correctly everywhere:

```
@media all and (max-width:620px), (max-device-width:620px){...}
```

However, when I try to get the width through jQuery:

```
alert($(window).width());
```

The value returns as 980.

I have found that using .innerWidth() yields the same result as .width().

According to [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/width/) $(window).width() returns the width of the browser viewport.

So why is it different from the css media query?

Comment: does the top solution here answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309859/css-media-queries-and-javascript-window-width-do-not-match

Comment: It is not do to a scrollbar, as there is not only no scrollbar on a mobile, but there is no browser scroll bar that I know of that is 360px wide.

Comment: Have you set the viewport meta? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Yes, I have, but this would not explain why the jQuery value & media query value are different.

Comment: Are you sure it is a 360px difference? It sound high to me...

Comment: It's at least a 360px difference. The media query is working & is set to 620px, the dimensions of the device is 534 x 854, & the value returned through jQuery is 980.