# how to calculate browser body width and height

Tags: html, css

how can i calculate body width and height for all browser in java query...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).ready(sizeContent01);
        function sizeContent01() {
            var totHeight = ($("body").height());
            var hdrHeight = $("#header").outerHeight(true);
            var ftrHeight = $("#footer").outerHeight(true);
            var bdyHeight1 = totHeight - hdrHeight - 10;
            var outputHeight = bdyHeight1 - $(".input_content").outerHeight(true) - 10;
            $("#body").css("height", bdyHeight1);
            $(".output_content").css("height", (outputHeight - 5));
        };
        $(window).resize(sizeContent02);
        function sizeContent02() {
            var totHeight = ($("body").height());
            var hdrHeight = $("#header").outerHeight(true);
            var ftrHeight = $("#footer").outerHeight(true);
            var bdyHeight1 = totHeight - hdrHeight - 10;
            var outputHeight = bdyHeight1 - $(".input_content").outerHeight(true) - 10;
            $("#body").css('height', bdyHeight1);
            $(".output_content").css('height', (outputHeight - 5));
        };
    });
```

please any one help me....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get height of entire document with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/how-to-get-height-of-entire-document-with-javascript)

Comment: jQuery doesn't stand for "Java Query". jQuery is built upon JavaScript. Java and JavaScript are two completely different languages. There's no actual documentation on what the `j` in jQuery stands for, however, it's most likely "JavaScript", but it could be "John" (Resig) - jQuery's founder.

Comment: Duplicate question. Search before posting question

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery : `$( window ).height();`
and in pure js : `window.innerHeight;`

Atleast ive done godly with these. Then if you want the height off whole html document (includes scrolling) you can use this with jQuery : `$( document ).height();`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).height();
$(window).width();
```

**More info**

- http://api.jquery.com/height/
- http://api.jquery.com/width/

If you think the scroll bar will be a problem you can try hiding them then taking your measurement

```
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
document.body.style.overflow = "";
```

Duplicate of [Get the height and width of the browser viewport without scrollbars using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794338/get-the-height-and-width-of-the-browser-viewport-without-scrollbars-using-jquery/8794370#8794370)