# How do I get the browser window's width, regardless of the body's scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The common ways to get the browser's width are all dependent on whether or not `<body>` has a scrollbar. For example, `window.innerWidth`, `document.documentElement.clientWidth`, `$(window).width()`, `$(window).outerWidth()`, etc all return different results for the following 2 cases:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>No scrollbar.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
<html>
<body>
<p style="height:10000px">Yes scrollbar.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

`$(window).width()`, etc, all return a higher value for the first case because the scrollbar's width is subtracted for the second case.

How can I reliably get the browser window's actual width regardless of the scrollbar's existence?

**Edit:** The suggested possible duplicate's answer says to use `$(window).width()` while I specifically said `$(window).width()` doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the height and width of the browser viewport without scrollbars using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794338/get-the-height-and-width-of-the-browser-viewport-without-scrollbars-using-jquery)

Comment: I just created 2 fiddles for you. and to my surprise the `window` width remains same even though scroll bar exists. **[Without ScrollBar](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ekLzxj6e/)** - **[Result](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ekLzxj6e/embedded/result/)**, **[With ScrollBar](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/7datv07o/)** - **[Result](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/7datv07o/embedded/result/)**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I think that may have to do with JSFiddle's iframes. Try `window.innerWidth` on a SO page, then delete all the content and try again. I got different widths.

Comment: @Linksku Again to my surprise I got same width.. **[With Scrollbar](http://postimg.org/image/petaq7055/)**, **[Without Scrollbar](http://postimg.org/image/3lkw7gi8l/)**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I found my mistake. I've always used `window.innerWidth` and `$(window).innerWidth()` interchangeably. However, it appears that `window.innerWidth` accounts for the scrollbar while `$(window).innerWidth()` doesn't. I will do more testing to see if `window.innerWidth` solves my problems. Thanks for helping me find the problem!

Comment: Sure.. Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try this**

I dont know whether this method is correct or no. But you will get actual width **677** of the sample window

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
    alert($(window).width());
    $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/m2xn6ue7/)

You will get the width of the window with the scroll bar as **677** when there is no overflow. [Demo for screen width without scroll bar](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/m2xn6ue7/1/)

You will get the width of the window with the scroll bar as **660** when there is overflow. [Demo for scree width with scroll bar.](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/m2xn6ue7/2/)

Comment: This worked, nice solution! However, this is sort of a "hacky" solution, so I'll leave this question open for a while and see if there's a cleaner solution.

Comment: @Linksku Ha ha... I liked the usage.. "Hacky"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice run down of [viewport properties from the Quirks Mode site](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html#link5).

The `window.innerWidth` is the simplest way of getting this (supported in IE9+ and all other browsers)

```
// Get the size of the viewport including scrollbars:
var width = window.innerWidth;
console.log('innerWidth=', width);
```

And here is the [MDN documentation on the `innerWidth` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth).