# Having issue with .outerheight()

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having issues with calculating the actual size of the navigator window, its returning a higher number than expected.

The actual code is the following:

```
function homeFullScreen() {

    var homeSection = $('.home');
    var windowHeight = $(window).outerHeight();

    if (homeSection.hasClass('home-fullscreen')) {

        $('.home-fullscreen').css('height', windowHeight);
    }
}
```

Also tried with .innerHeight() and .height() but doesn't work. The expected output is 820px but result is:

```
.home { height: 47677px; }
```

And this number changes even if I modify the width of the navigator window. In mobile devices number is much higher.

Does somebody figure out what is happening here?

Thank you,

Alejandra | aleare

Comment: This is the desired output. You probably are looking for `$(window).height();`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794338/get-the-height-and-width-of-the-browser-viewport-without-scrollbars-using-jquery

Comment: I've also tried this:
 var windowHeight = $(window).height();

But look at the result:
    height: 10359px;

Comment: **SOLVED** Solution was so simple and easy! Just deleted this JQuery code and added a property to the section: `code`height:100vh;`code` and it works fine in both mobile and desktop.