# How to make DIV take the full height of Browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

I want to make a DIV with height 100% to take the full height of the **Browser Window** not just the Viewport height.

The outer DIV has **Display** property **Flex**.

The target DIV has class called **full-height-div**

That is HTML code

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="full-height-div">
        
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
        
    </div>
</div>
```

and that is CSS code

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.main-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}

.full-height-div {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: what do you think the *full height of the Browser Window* is? the "window" is potentially infinite in height, is it not? the more you add, the higher it gets - unless "browser window" means something different to what I'm guessing

Comment: The problem is that when the DIV which has class 'main-content' has height greater than viewport, the height of the target DIV is still in view port height

Comment: Ok then can you review this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794338/get-the-height-and-width-of-the-browser-viewport-without-scrollbars-using-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794338/get-the-height-and-width-of-the-browser-viewport-without-scrollbars-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want `<div class="full-height-div">` to be the height of its *parent*.

`.main-container` needs `flex-direction: row`, not `height: 100%`.

In this example, `<div class="full-height-div">` (outlined in red) takes on the height of its parent `div.main-container` (outlined in green).

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.main-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;    
    border: 5px solid green;
    width: 100%;
}

.full-height-div {
    height: 2000px; /* just to force it to be taller than the viewport in this example */
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="full-height-div">
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

This was answered here: [How can I make Flexbox children 100% height of their parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381172/how-can-i-make-flexbox-children-100-height-of-their-parent)

Answer (score 1):

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.full-height-div {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color:blue;
}

.main-container {
    display: flex;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="full-height-div">
        full
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
        main
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.full-height-div {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Not work, I want DIV to be full height of Browser not Viewport

Comment: If main-content DIV has height greater than Viewport then it not work