# How to get the actual width available for content on the browser window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, positioning

I'm positioning my elements using JavaScript. In order to do it perfectly I have to get the amount of horizontal space available. Badly, `$(window).width()` does not take in account the scrollbar width. The result is this:

[bad http://dl.dropbox.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/fb.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/fb.png)

Here, "Pagina 1" is contained in a small div that was supposed to align with the right border of the window. Well, it does - literally - ignoring the scrollbar, which covers part of the div, throwing the "1" of "Página 1" to the next line.

Comment: Why don't you just use `position: fixed;`? You shouldn't need to use JavaScript to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery - how to get screen width without scrollbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339377/jquery-how-to-get-screen-width-without-scrollbar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this function

```
function scrollbar_width() {

        var calculation_content = $('<div style="width:50px;height:50px;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:-200px;left:-200px;"><div style="height:100px;"></div>');
        jQuery('body').append(calculation_content);
        var width_one = jQuery('div', calculation_content).innerWidth();
        calculation_content.css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
        var width_two = jQuery('div', calculation_content).innerWidth();
        jQuery(calculation_content).remove();
        return (width_one - width_two);

    }
```

now calculate available with

```
var availableWidth = $(window).width() - scrollbar_width();
```

Comment: Haven't tested it particularly because I managed to solve before, but my result is similar.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to two previous questions:

[how to get innerWidth of an element in jquery WITHOUT scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692598/how-to-get-innerwidth-of-an-element-in-jquery-without-scrollbar)

and

[How to get screen width without (minus) scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339377/jquery-how-to-get-screen-width-without-scrollbar)