# Get div height without the scrollbar

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to get the height of an horizontally and vertically scrollable div without taking into account the horizontal scrollbar ?
I am trying to get the height of the visible portion of my div.

Comment: It is not exactly the same, but this deals with getting width from one with a vertical bar, and you could likely implement a similar solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692598/how-to-get-innerwidth-of-an-element-in-jquery-without-scrollbar Basically, it recommended putting a div inside the other, make the width (or in your case the height) 100%, and you can give it zero width, and then get the height of the inside one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

**html**

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

using jQuery

```
var width = $('.div1')[0]['clientWidth'];
var height = $('.div1')[0]['clientHeight'];
```

**working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/7xmun47a/

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be looking for `window.getComputedStyle(element, null)`. The documentation can be found on [mdn documentation's site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle).

An example would look like:

```
var container = document.getElementById("whatever");
var computed = window.getComputedStyle(container, null).getPropertyValue("height");
// or pass width to getPropertyValue
```

This should give you the width minus the scrollbars.

[jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/mixufagoro/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: does not work for mozilla it is including the height and width of the scroll bar as well

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two ways to retrieve the visible width or height of an element.

1. The first way is to use `offsetHeight` or `offsetWidth`:
   These guys return the VISIBLE height or width of you element including: BORDER, PADDING, SCROLLBAR AND MARGIN.

You use them like this `yourDiv.offsetHeight`

2. The second way is to use `clientHeight` or `clientWidth`: These ones are the same as the ones above EXCEPT they only return the VISIBLE HEIGHT` or VISIBLE WIDTH AND PADDING but without borders, scrollbar, and margins.

Referrences:

[clientWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.clientWidth)

[clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.clientHeight)

[offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetWidth)

[offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetHeight)

Hope this helps

Answer (score -4):

you can use overflow-y for vertical or overflow-x for horizontal

```
overflow-y:scroll;
```

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the question