# How do I feature-detect the window height and width in a way that includes IE 6, 7, and 8?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

```
if (typeof(window.innerWidth) === 'number')
```

catches Chrome and Firefox and gives fairly obvious means to determine the window height and width.

What features should I be detecting to get comparable data (I know identical may not be an option) to also catch IE6, 7, and 8?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery - how to get screen width without scrollbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339377/jquery-how-to-get-screen-width-without-scrollbar)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using jQuery for this, particularly with the cross-browser requirements.

In jQuery, you have `$(window).width()`, so you can do what you want to do very easily.

```
var winWidth  = $(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
var docWidth = $(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document
```

See also: http://api.jquery.com/width/