# Media queries and scrollbar width

Tags: css, cross-browser, scrollbar, media-queries

I am working on a layout that needs precise media query handling. One of my issues is the crossbrowser **scrollbar width** as it is different according to browsers and most (all of them?) include it in the window width.

As we can see in these 2 examples, the media queries don't act at the same window size with and without the vertical scrollbar :

1. [Test without scrollbar](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/z5fHt/8/)
2. [Test with scrollbar](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/z5fHt/)

In the first example, you can see the background color change exactly at `800/700/600px` window width.
In the second examples with the scrollbar the colors change at :

- Chrome and firefox : `779/679/579px`
- IE : `783/783/583px`

That makes a difference of up to `21px`.

Is there is a work around by ignoring the scrollbar in media queries and focus on the available width itself. 
If not how do you handle this issue, do you fix a maximum width for the scollbar and include it in the media queries?

-- **UPDATE** --

I am searching for best practices/solution with CSS as I would like to avoid JS for this project.

Comment: Its look similar to other task. Try this one:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976531/dealing-with-scroll-bars-and-jquery-width-method]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976531/dealing-with-scroll-bars-and-jquery-width-method

Comment: @Nividim I had seen this question but the answer doesn't fit my needs, I am looking for a css solution.

Comment: @web-tiki, my answer helped you? any comments? it is not accepted, let me know if something wrong, please, I will try to add additional info or explaining.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Your answer is interesting, links are consistent that is why I upvoted it. But  I was searching for a CSS solution and best practices without JS. Maybe it wasn't clear in my question, I'll update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eight years later (2023), [container queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries) are [supported in most browsers](https://caniuse.com/css-container-queries) and come to the rescue!

Instead of using a media query (which, as you found, reports a window width *including* the scrollbar), we declare a 'containment context' on the html element

```
html{container-type:inline-size;}
```

... and then use a container query to get it's width (*without* the scrollbar):

```
@container(max-width:600px){
  body{background:gray;}
}
```

I've [updated your example](http://jsfiddle.net/3bqxj6p7/) 'Test with scrollbar' using a container query approach (leaving html and javascript untouched).

Comment: beware though - i just found out that 'position:fixed' inside the body won't work anymore when using 'container-type' on the 'html' or 'body' elements

Comment: regarding my previous comment on the 'position:fixed' issue, there new seems to be a solution to this: https://www.oddbird.net/2023/07/05/contain-root/#tl%3Bdr%2C-can-we-have-a-root-container%3F

Answer (score 6):

Look this example: http://stowball.github.io/mqGenie/

It is working fine both in Firefox and in Chrome for me (with scrollbars).

You can download and read more about this plugin here: https://github.com/stowball/mqGenie (~2.2 kb)

One of sources: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21414947/2898694

Enjoy.