# Disable scrolling but keep scrollbar CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't find a solution to this, there was a question over here, but the answers are not very usable (at least for me).

I have a JavaScript modal pop-up that disables everything on the background by placing transparent div over the page. It also disables the scrolling by setting the overflow to hidden, and must do so, because the page is scrollable with the mouse wheel otherwise and distracts the user.

The problem is, when hiding and showing the scrollbar the page resizes and the effect is ugly. Also, my page is designed in such a way that if I stop it from resizing that would be ugly either.

What I want is to disable the scrollbar, but keep it visible (the page content is longer than the screen fits). Is this somehow possible in CSS?

Comment: please show some code

Comment: For what exactly? I mean really, for which part? The entire code is fairly complicated, with JS dynamically adding elements.

Comment: I have no idea of how this page works and how you made it. How can you expect I understand which or where is the problem and if it's possible to fix it in CSS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Just disable scroll not hide it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701754/just-disable-scroll-not-hide-it)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of changing the `css`, which will remove the `scrollbar`, and as you said change the layout of the page, try calling a `jquery function` instead.

```
// call your pop up and inside that function add below
$('body').on('scroll mousewheel touchmove', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      return false;
});
```

then when you close the modal, call the same function but replace `on` with `off`

Comment: Yeah, again no simple CSS solution when there should be, and there is not a reason why. Thank you, will use JS/jQuery

Comment: Good idea, but it also blocks any scroll inside the popup.

Comment: Btw, users can still scroll the content by dragging the scrollbar with mouse after that.

Answer (score 3):

Since scrollbars are not all 17px wide, I solved this with JavaScript. That is, I calculated the exact width of the scrollbar and added an equal amount of margin to the right of the body element. This also works when the scrollbar isn't present due to a high resolution or a lack of content.

```
function toggleMenu() {
   // get width before hiding scrollbar
   let oldWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

   // toggle CSS class that sets overflow to hidden
   document.body.classList.toggle('MenuOpen');

   // get new width after hiding scrollbar
   let newWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

   // set margin-right value equal to width of the scrollbar
   let scrollbarWidth = Math.max(0, newWidth - oldWidth);
   document.body.style.marginRight = `${scrollbarWidth}px`;
}
```

...and my CSS looks like:

```
html {
    background-color: #e6e6e6; /* color of fake scrollbar */
}

body.MenuOpen {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you start showing your popup, give the `body` a class (like `popupOpen`). This should be an easy workaround.

```
.popupOpen {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 17px //size of the scrollbar in each browser
}
```

When you close your popup, simply remove the class from the `body`.

Comment: Nice to know that about the scrollbar, but I can't do that. If the page is wiewed in higher resolution there won't be scrollbar, so this will screw it. Also, my page, well, I recreate something very similar to this free template: http://www.wix.com/website-template/view/html/1410?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wix.com%2Fwebsite%2Ftemplates%2Fhtml%2Fbusiness-services%2F6&bookName=create-master-new&galleryDocIndex=2&category=business-services&metaSiteId=&viewMode=desktop Simply resizing or leaving more margin is very much visible, my margins are exen less than on this template...

Comment: are all `scrollbars` the same width on all browsers on all devices?

Comment: The scrollbar width isn't the same on all browsers.

Comment: according to this, they are: http://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/browser-scrollbar-width.php

Comment: and if not you could use `.css()` and this script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079187/how-to-calculate-the-width-of-the-scroll-bar

Comment: can the user change the width of their scrollbar?  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-to-adjust-the-width-of-the-scrollbar-in/b45bf22b-4882-45e1-9b3c-5051da0dc631

Comment: @DomlThe-Bread that source is wrong according to [my tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180488/media-queries-and-scrollbar-width)

Comment: good test ! (y) yeah as i mentioned above, you could calculate the width of the scrollbar and add inline css with jquery!