# Jquery $(window).width() excluding scrollbar width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a page that sets a lot of css properties using javascript and it uses $(window).width() to determine the page width. Among other things, it sets some div widths to be the full width of the page using that method. A It's done this way because a lot of the other calculations are done in javascript.

Anyway, I'm switching to a different navigation style and I set the body's overflow-y to be hidden. Unfortunately, now that the scrollbar has disappeared I'm left with a lovely white bar at the side of my page (in every browser I've tried) that is exactly the width of the scroll bar. Without specifically calculating the width of the scroll bar, which can get messy, how can I just get the width of the full browser including the scroll bar?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** It was an order of operations issue, I was being an idiot.  Sorry!

Comment: Try using $('body').width() if your body is set to 100%

Comment: That didn't work either, unfortunately.

Comment: if you set `html, body { overflow-y: hidden; }` does it resolve?  I've found certain settings that reset best with targeting both `html` and `body`.  So is the question how to GET the width, or how to PREVENT that white bar?

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the order of operations... Can you set the body's overflow-y to hidden **BEFORE** you do the rest of your sizing?

Comment: I just found the problem.  I apologize for wasting everyone's time, as it WAS an order of operations thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get screen width without (minus) scrollbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339377/how-to-get-screen-width-without-minus-scrollbar)

Answer (score 3):

`window.outerWidth`

The outerWidth property sets or returns the outer width of a window, including all interface elements (like toolbars/scrollbars).

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_outerheight.asp

Answer (score 0):

use document instead

```
$(document).width()
```

Comment: Google-surfers don't let this answer scare you away. You can also do this without jQuery using `document.width`

Comment: I hope they would not see this answer if they were not searching the tearm `jQuery`.  Thank you for the comment though

Comment: Neither $(document).width() nor document.width worked...I still see a white bar where there should be a scrollbar. :/

Comment: A fiddle won't really work here because it's something specific to the page width, it's not just a div.

Comment: @Mr.Lavalamp JSbin will let you view the page in full

Comment: And JSFiddles run the page in an iFrame which can be opened up. Either way!