# Add the width of scrollbar to the window width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following line would run the function inside it when the width is above 770px and below 1024px - the question is, how can I include the width of the scrollbar to it?

```
if (width < 1024 && width > 770) {}
```

I already tried implementing `window.pageXOffset` or window.innerWidth with no hope!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery $(window).width() excluding scrollbar width?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802036/jquery-window-width-excluding-scrollbar-width)

Comment: Mate I already did my research, I tried the answers on there but none is working!

Comment: You said you tried `pageXOffset` and `innerWidth`. Did you try `outerWidth` ?

Comment: yes I tried it like "if ($(window).outerWidth () < 770) {" is the way I applied it correct?

Comment: Check this link ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382516/getting-scroll-bar-width-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if (window.outerWidth< 1024 && window.outerWidth > 770) {}`

> window.outerWidth gets the width of the outside of the browser window. It represents the width of the whole browser window including sidebar (if expanded), window chrome and window resizing borders/handles.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.outerWidth

Comment: There is a small problem however, It worked on this function nicely: http://jsfiddle.net/pvC6s/ but when not on this one http://jsfiddle.net/a7Rps/ why is that mate?

Comment: 2nd one works fine for me after i added some `console.log()`to test it out

Comment: Did you use $(window).on("load resize", function() {
      if (window.outerWidth < 1024 && window.outerWidth > 770) {

Comment: This is not supported by IE8 ... this is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382516/getting-scroll-bar-width-using-javascript