# Centering absolute positioned DIV even after window re-size (for responsive design)

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I want to keep an absolute positioned DIV `#box` at the middle of the screen even after window re-size and for all major device (responsive design). Responsive #box is done using css3 media queries  while `left` is calculated using jquery. But I can positioned my box exactly at the center, on window re-size for small screen there is unequal left & right margins.

```
<HTML>

<body>
    <div id ="box">
      <a> is am athe centre?'</a>
    </div>
</body>



</HTML>
```

css :

```
 #box {
      position:absolute;
      background:red; 
      width:900px; 
      height:400px;
      }

@media only screen and (min-width: 979px)


{
 #box{width:760px;background:yellow;}
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)

{
#box{width:760px;background:pink;}
}



@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) 

{
#box{width:460px;background:black;}
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 479px) 

{
#box{width:300px;background:blue;}
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) 

{
#box{width:300px;background:grey;}
}
```

jQuery :

```
function leftmargin(){
 var w_box    =  ($('#box').width());
 var w_window = $(window).width();
 var w_left = (w_window - w_box)/2 ;
 $("#box").css("left", w_left + "px");
}

$(window).resize(function() {
   leftmargin();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   leftmargin();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Center the box using CSS ([source](http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/)), then adapt the `width` and the `margin-left` in you media queries:

```
#box {
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:760px;
    height:30px;
    background:yellow;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-380px; /* half of the box */
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    #box {
        background:pink;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)  {
    #box {
        width:460px;
        background:black;
        margin-left:-230px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 479px)  {
    #box {
        width:300px;
        background:blue;
        margin-left:-150px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    #box {
        background:grey;
    }
}
```

Demo here, drag the inner frame boundary to „simulate device sizes“: http://jsfiddle.net/hD657/3/

Solution based on your JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/NnDvs/

---

Answer to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927009/centering-absolute-positioned-div-even-after-window-re-size-for-responsive-desi/17927622?noredirect=1#comment26194364_17927622):

`margin-left` is calculated based on the width of the box, so this is independent on any viewport or window width. I guess from your comment that your box is just off by some pixels (you should state that more clearly so we can help better). jQuery's `width` will return the width "without" the scrollbar, so it changes based on the height of the contents (i.e. if there is a scrollbar or not). You could try to "hide" the scrollbars temporary before getting the width: `document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";`. But in general, I would say that the returned value of `.width()` should be what you are looking for. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the answer !This is close to what actually I want.  This works fine on specific screen sizes. But I want to implement margin-left using jquery, so even on single pixel re-size my div box remains always at the center.

Comment: This is what the `left:50%` actually does. Does the width of your box change when the viewport width is changed by 1px? Then see my JavaScript solution. The value for `margin-left` is set on `resize` and calculated using the current width of the box.

Comment: Updated the second solution, the box is now `30%` wide, so it changes constantly: http://jsfiddle.net/NnDvs/1/

Comment: Its nice Wolfarm ! I already have provided the same along with my question, Now I have one doubt that we are calculating leftmargin using  window width and not the actually viewport width . Is window width include vertical scrollbar width too?.if it is, then this 17px width of scroll-bar responsible for unequal margin on both side while resizing .

Comment: Updated my answer, as the comment became too long.

Comment: I want to confirm whether window.width() returns 1024 px or 1024-17px  for 1024 x 768 screen,as I can see your suggested code is perfect to work with. But for small screen I can see my box doesn't remains at center by some pixel. As now I am checking with having scroll-bar for all screen widths. so I think I am centering DIV on viweport width but maginLeft is evaluated using window width.

Comment: Thanks wolfram for your valuable help! just referenced this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339377/jquery-how-to-get-screen-width-without-scrollbar

Answer (score 3):

You can just add this and not even need media queries or javascript (since you know the size of the box):

```
#box {
  position:absolute;
  background:red; 
  width:900px; 
  height:400px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -200px; // half total width (border, padding, and width)
  margin-left: -450px; // half total height (border, padding, and width)
}
```

And if you didn't know the width, but were okay with just targeting modern browsers that support transform, replace the `margins` with:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Comment: This is okey for large screen with fixed width and height; but my #box with variable width and height for responsive design.

Comment: Then use the second option. It will work even if you use percentages for height and width. Media queries and transforms have the same browser-share, so you could easily use your javascript for older browsers that don't support transforms.

Answer (score 1):

Take the `width` and `height` in `%`.

See this fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WChsw/2/)

I have added:

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#box {
      position:absolute;
      background:red; 
      width:80%; 
      height:40%;
      margin-left: 10%;
      margin-top: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion aayushi! But I want to stick with exact width and not with percentage width.

Comment: Ok, check the updated fiddle then, change `width: 900px and height: 450px;` and test.

Comment: Its works well! as width is in proportion with window width. But in my case Box width is for different screen sizes are different.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you want, centering an absolute positioned div is easy but what's this about responsive design and variable width/height?

The best I can come up with is to use display table cell:

```
html {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#box {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #c00;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f00dmonsta/cZC3g/

Comment: see my css3 media queries! for different screen sizes my #box having different width ( width varying according to screen size) . So I want to center my #box for all screen sizes.

Comment: you can use your media queries, the setup above should center a `#box` of any width/height...