# Cannot get width of screen without scrollbar using cross-browser expression

Tags: javascript

I am using the following expression in JavaScript to get the width of screen, which seems to work fine except that it includes the width of vertical scroll-bar when scrolling is there.

```
var wMax = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0)
```

**Question**: How can the above cross-browser expression be modified so it gives the width of screen excluding the vertical scrollbar? *I need to use JavaScript for this and not jQuery.*

**UPDATE 1:**

I found the following cross-browser expression to give the width excluding the vertical scroll-bar.

```
var wMax = Math.min(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth 
                      || screen.width);
```

1. I used Math.min rather than Math.max, so that whichever width was less was taken for width
2. and also used screen.width instead of 0 in the original expression since screen.width would always be maximum of all widths in this case for all browsers as it will always include scroll-bars.

Comment: `window.innerWidth` should be cross browser (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.innerWidth)? That will give you the same width with or without the scrollbar.

Comment: Like I said the above expression is cross-browser, but it is giving the width with scrollbar. Will window.innerWidth work for IE, Chrome, FireFox, Opera? You are suggesting to just use : var wMax =  window.innerWidth?

Comment: @putvande, Actually I got the cross-browser expression from another post on StackOverflow and the answer did not mention to use only window.innerWidth as a cross-browser solution to getting screen viewport width.

Comment: The website I linked to says most browsers are supported.

Comment: @putvande, I used the expression under UPDATE 1 which always gives the width without scroll-bar. I tested it and it works perfectly.

Comment: @putvande, I think window.innerWidth will not work in IE8 and below, but the expressions mentioned in this post will work in IE8 and below.

Comment: You should not be using `screen.width`. The browser window may not be maximized, the user may be using multiple monitors, and `screen.width` is not part of any standard.

Comment: jQuery just uses `document.documentElement.clientWidth` for its `$(window).width()` calculation.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, What, in your view, could possibly be used instead of screen.width in the expression under UPDATE 1? I resized my browser window to less than maximum and still the expression under UPDATE 1 worked when using screen width.

Comment: I may have misread/misinterpreted your question, reading it again I see that I don't quite understand what is being asked. Your questions reads "width of screen excluding the vertical scrollbar?", does that mean the browser's viewport width?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, Yes.

Comment: Testing in Chrome, `document.documentElement.clientWidth` gives the width of the viewport without scrollbar.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/8339377/1136253

Answer (score 1):

`screen.width` is the width of the display screen, not the window of the browser excluding the scroll bar.

You should use `Math.min` instead of `Math.max` since the width without the scroll bar is going to be smaller than the width with scroll bars.

Also if there is a browser that does not work properly, you could try getting the width of the body or html tag without `clientWidth` like this `document.documentElement.scrollWidth`.