# JavaScript getting the wrong window size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am messing around with some code and applying / removing classes based on window size and I'm running into a weird error.  I've confirmed that I'm at the default zoom (if that matters), and I've replicated the issue in FF & Chrome.

I have a resize event handler that I'm just using to monitor the javascript window width value vs. the actual value (I have a chrome extension which shows the window & viewport width as you're resizing, and my bootstrap viewports hit exactly as they should at 992px, 1200px etc, so I know that the javascripts value is off for some reason and not vice-versa)

For some reason, as I resize the window, the value for window width that shows in the `console.log`, is always 21px smaller than the actual screen size. This is the code that I'm using for the test:

```
var w = 0;
    $(function () {
        w = $(window).innerWidth() || $(window).width();
    })
    
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if (w != $(window).innerWidth()) {
            w = $(window).innerWidth() || $(window).width();
            console.log(w);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is it because you have dev tools open, making the screen shorter?

Comment: I keep dev tools in a separate window on my other screen

Comment: 21px smaller - scrollbar width, maybe?

Comment: I'm thinking that's it.  I just took a ruler extension from chrome and it won't let me select the scrollbar, so I did the whole width of the rest of the page and it matched exactly what javascript is recording for the width..is there a reason that JavaScript wouldn't include the scrollbar inherently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
var iw = $('body').innerWidth();
```

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/kimaq/1/edit)**

answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8340177/504836

Comment: I added your snippet out of curiosity to my `console.log` and it's recording the same answer as the variable `w` which is window width. - w 883
(index):404 body 883
(index):403 w 880
(index):404 body 880
(index):403 w 879
(index):404 body 879

Comment: You might have to set the body margin to 0 for this to work.

Comment: I just checked the inspector out of curiosity and this was the rule : body {
    margin: 0;
}