# jquery window width not working at some breakpoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, document-body, outerwidth

I wrote a script that loads some html from files based on the width of window.

The problem is that at some points it fails to work

```
var winWidth = $(window).width();
//var winWidth = window.outerWidth;
//var winWidth = document.body.offsetWidth;


    if((winWidth > 0) && (winWidth <= 767)){
        console.log('Mobile');
        $.ajax({
            url : "home-banner-parts/mobile.html",
            dataType: "html",
            success : function (data) {
                $("#homeslider").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    if((winWidth >= 768) && (winWidth <= 1279)){
        console.log('Tab');
        $.ajax({
            url : "home-banner-parts/tab.html",
            dataType: "html",
            success : function (data) {
                $("#homeslider").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    if((winWidth >= 1280)){
        console.log('Desktop');
        $.ajax({
            url : "home-banner-parts/desktop.html",
            dataType: "html",
            success : function (data) {
                $("#homeslider").html(data);
            }
        });
    }


//the above code is wrapped in function
$(window).resize(function() {
    console.log('Resizing');
    homeCarousel();
});
```

So the problem comes around width

- 1281px to 1295px - loads tab.html but should load sektop.html
- 770px 785px - loads mobile.html but should load tab.html

Please help

Comment: Can you add console.log(winWidth); above your IF-statements to track the current width?

Comment: I did, and it does not show the correct one that is shown by chrome on resizing - there is  a mismatch.

Comment: Oh, You're resizing. You need to use $(window).on('load resize', function () { // code here.});

Comment: @cosmoonot - I call this code withinin $(window).resize(function() {}. Should I use on('load resize') instead..?

Comment: Yes, because your code is only checking for resize at the moment. Use the answer below, or the code I posted above.

Comment: Just a tip, it is better to use `winWidth > 767 ...` when the previous check was `winWidth <= 767`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pixel range, that your code fails, points to the scrollbar width.

Indeed, you need to use `window.innerWidth` to get the actual viewport used.

So `var winWidth = window.innerWidth;`

Finally you should also call you code when the dom is ready, so

```
function handleWindowSize(){
   // your code here
}
$(window).resize(function() {
    console.log('Resizing');
    handleWindowSize();
    homeCarousel();
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).trigger('resize');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap everything in a `$(window).on('load resize', function() { ... });` event handler so that this code runs when the page `load`s and on the `resize` event.

I would also track the state somewhere so that you aren't unnecessarily firing `$.load()` if what you want to load is already on the page.

```js
var $body = $('body');

    $(window).on('load resize', function() {
      
      var winWidth = $(this).width(),
          state = $body.data('state');

      console.log(winWidth);

      if ((winWidth > 0) && (winWidth <= 767) && (state != 'mobile')) {
        $body.data('state','mobile');
        console.log('Mobile');
        $.ajax({
          url: "home-banner-parts/mobile.html",
          dataType: "html",
          success: function(data) {
            $("#homeslider").html(data);
          }
        });
      }
      if ((winWidth >= 768) && (winWidth <= 1279) && (state != 'tab')) {
        $body.data('state','tab');
        console.log('Tab');
        $.ajax({
          url: "home-banner-parts/tab.html",
          dataType: "html",
          success: function(data) {
            $("#homeslider").html(data);
          }
        });
      }
      if ((winWidth >= 1280) && (state != 'desktop')) {
        $body.data('state','desktop');
        console.log('Desktop');
        $('bo')
        $.ajax({
          url: "home-banner-parts/desktop.html",
          dataType: "html",
          success: function(data) {
            $("#homeslider").html(data);
          }
        });
      }
    })
```

```css
body {
overflow-y: scroll;
min-height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The above code is wrapped in a function. I call the function on load and resize..Updated the code

Comment: @StacyJ updated what code? It's not in your OP. My demo seems to work. Does it work for you?

Comment: @StacyJ You're only checking for resize at the moment, you want load and resize.

Comment: @StacyJ also updated my answer to add a method to track state so `$.load()` doesn't fire unless the file isn't currently loaded.

Comment: I'll try this - but on load resize does not work for me

Comment: @StacyJ please be more specific. "but on load resize does not work for me" - why? Does my demo work? And if not, please tell me *why* or give me some feedback if you'd like me to help. It's a very straightforward concept.

Comment: ok, i tried your updated script and at 1296 on chrome it shows Tab in the console. But it should show Desktop

Comment: @MichaelCoker - ur snippet however works fine. I am not sure whats wrong with my implementation

Comment: @StacyJ it doesn't load the wrong resource at 1296 for me. Here's a screenshot of the page loaded at 1275 - 1299 and it loads the right file http://i.imgur.com/ot7vXWR.png Feel free to include everything you have so I can look, but I can't help if you can't reproduce it. All I can do is guess.

Comment: @MichaelCoker - there is a mismatch the width when I console log it. For width 1292 on chrome it logs 1275

Comment: @MichaelCoker Do you think it is because of the scrollbar....your snippet does't have a scrollbar

Comment: @StacyJ "For width 1292 on chrome it logs 1275" - how are you seeing it's 1292px? When I have the dev tools open, and compare the width in the top/right of the window (which shows the window width) it matches the # in the console log. And I'm using chrome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141293/discussion-between-stacy-j-and-michael-coker).

Comment: @StacyJ could be, I added a scrollbar to my snippet if you want to try again. If so, you can either adjust your media queries or use `innerWidth` like @Gaby suggested, or one of the techniques here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339377/how-to-get-screen-width-without-minus-scrollbar

Comment: @MichaelCoker - innerwidth worked for me. Thanks for bringing up the state..it helps a lot.