# How can i run some JQ code, only when the user screen resolution is higher than X?

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

How can i run some JQ code, only when the user screen resolution is higher/lower than X?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with pure JS:

```
if(screen.width>=1024)
{
   myFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well i'd advise against using screen resolution because not everyone maximizes their window (let alone full-screens it). Check the **window** width/height, and do whatever accordingly:

```
var winW = $(window).width(),
    winH = $(window).height();

if ( winW > X && winH > Y) { 
    waWaWeeWah(); // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Newer browsers allow you to detect the user's screen resolution using the screen.width and screen.height properties, like I show in my answer

Comment: Yeah I see that, completely forgot! +1

Answer (score 1):

Use window event listener, e.g.:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if( $(window).width() < yourThreshold ){

        // do your business

    }
});
```

Comment: can i use css selectors with JQ to acomplish this? because when i use `$(window).width()` it dosent count the scroll bar, and its not dynamic

Comment: Have a look around, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596072/detect-window-width-and-compensate-for-scrollbars-javascript

Answer (score 0):

What about this suggestion I was trying to get some feedback on, it ties js to media queries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203220/suggestion-for-responsive-design-jquery-and-mobile-sites